# Loopback is not responding with modified data after 'loaded' hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have the following code in my Model.js file.

```js
Model.observe('loaded', (ctx, next) => {
  const {
    data,
    options: {
      user
    }
  } = ctx;
  const owner = (user && data && user.uid === data.userId) || false;
  console.log(
    `${data.id}: loaded - access by ${user && user.name}, owner:${owner}`
  );
  if (!owner) {
    delete data.testProp1;
  }
  console.log('returning: ', ctx.data);
  next();
});
```

When I make a request, I see the following log output (server logs):

```js
f3f9ffd6-14dc-42e5-94ba-503aa3426faa: loaded - access by User1, owner:false
returning:
{
  testProp2: true,
  id: 'f3f9ffd6-14dc-42e5-94ba-503aa3426faa',
  userId: 'sfeywkKSuBTlf0DwE4ZOFd8RX5E3'
}
```

But then in the actual response the browser receives I actually get:

```js
{ 
  testProp1: true,
  testProp2: true,
  id: 'f3f9ffd6-14dc-42e5-94ba-503aa3426faa',
  userId: 'sfeywkKSuBTlf0DwE4ZOFd8RX5E3' 
}
```

Is there something in the documentation I am missing?  Deleting the property is exactly what it shows in the Loopback docs [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#operation-options).  Also, I actually see the modified data as the `data` property on the `ctx` object before calling `next()`.  Anyone run into this issue or know some caveat to the docs that isn't explicitly stated?

Comment: Finding it difficult to find a solution on this one.

Comment: @sidewaiise Ah, so actually I found what was causing the issue.  I had a default value defined for the model.  When you do that if you don't have a value when it responds with the type, it will add the default value.  It is very much unclear that would/could occur based on the documentation though.

Comment: What do you mean 'default  value defined for the model'? Do you mean you had set a default value for one of the model properties?

Comment: If So, I'm trying to perform an operation on an extended model of the User model... we don't really have any default values set for that. Strage thing is, it only stopped working recenly. Would prefer to use observer than remote hook.